# Large symmetric list in python: will references contribute to size in ram?

Tags: python, list, reference, size, ram

I have a very large python 2D list L, that is symmetric, i.e. `L[x][y]==L[y][x]`. It holds integer tuples. The way I create it is that I first set the values of `L[x][y]` for all possible x and y such that x<=y. Then I set `L[x][y]=L[y][x]` for all x and y such that x>y, so that I don't have to check all the time whether for a pair [x][y] I have x>=y or xL[x][y].

How is the size of this list affected? My logic says that because `L[x][y]` for x>y holds a reference and not a tuple, then it shouldn't take as much space in RAM. Is that the case? If I just set `L[x][y]` for only `x<=y`, do I get a list of around half the size?

Comment: Yes -- It should be smaller.  How much smaller depends on the size of the tuples, but somewhere near a factor of 2 is probably a reasonable expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - yes.  But to prove it let's take two examples and use [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).

**Version 1, no references**

```
def build_symmetric_list(n) :
    l = []
    for x in range(0,n) :
        ll = []
        for y in range(0,n) :
            if x<= y:
                ll.append((x,y))
            else :
                ll.append((y,x))
        l.append(ll)
    return l

@profile
def test_a():
    a = build_symmetric_list(1000)

test_a()
```

-

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
    13    9.848 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
    14                             def test_a():
    15  106.941 MiB   97.094 MiB    a = build_symmetric_list(1000)
```

**Version 2, with references**

```
def build_symmetric_list_with_references(n) :
    l = []
    for x in range(0,n) :
        ll = []
        for y in range(0,n) :
            if x<= y :
                ll.append((x,y))
            else :
                ll.append(l[y][x]) #by reference
        l.append(ll)
    return l

@profile
def test_b() :
    b = build_symmetric_list_with_references(1000)
test_b()
```

and the results:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    13    9.848 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
    14                             def test_b() :
    15   65.047 MiB   55.199 MiB    b = build_symmetric_list_with_references(1000)
```

So 97 mb vs 55 - so about half.  Keep in mind that because tuples are immutable, a reassignment to  L[x][y] won't be reflected in L[y][x] (possibly invalidating the symmetry of your list).